# Зачем нужны кавычки и фигурные скобки: "{$this->name}"?

Tags: php

Всем добрый день, объясните, пожалуйста, смысл следующей записи.

```
        public function get_Info($name,$surname){

            $this->name    = $name;
            $this->surname = $surname;

            return "{$this->name}"."{$this->surname}";
        }
```

Для него нужны ковычки и фигурные скобки внутри них? Почему нельзя было просто написать

```
return $this->name.$this->surname;
```

Comment: ЕМНИП, это ничего не даёт, скорее наоборот, некрасиво.

Comment: Да действительно непонятно зачем засорять код лишним мусором! Просто вот уже не первый раз встречаю подобную запись,и решил узнать что она означает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[string expansion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

в примере вероятно приведение к строке, можно было написать

```
return "".$this->name.$this->surname;
```

или

```
return "{$this->name}{$this->surname}";
```

хотя, конкатинация сама по себе к строке приводит, в целом смысла нет так делать здесь.

вот наглядная иллюстрация:

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
echo gettype($a.$b);
```

а еще кажется пробел бы тут не помешал :)

к такому коду может привести какое-то спец образование (шаблон из университета) , например мой американский коллега всегда переменные в bash пишет

```
echo "${var}";
```

Comment: это наглядная иллюстрация, простите, чего? :)

Comment: того что конкатинация сама по себе приводит к строке

Answer (score 4):

Пример тот что вы предоставили будет работать и без фигурных скобок.

```
return "$this->name $this->surname";
```

Это будет работать для простых переменных и для свойств объектов. И даже для элементов массивов, но только в этом случае не следует ставить кавычки у строковых ключей, например

```
return "$greeting, $this->name, ваш баланс $stats[balance]";
```

Реальное применение скобкам начинается, когда вы захотите поместить в строку переменные с вложенностью больше одного.

```
return "Привет, $this->name['key']";
```

здесь РНР решит, что переменная, которую надо вывести, - это `$this->name`, и выдаст ошибку. Но скобки заставят его работать

```
return "Привет, {$this->name['key']}";
```

то же касается и вывода вложенных массивов - `$array[1][2]` можно вывести только в фигурных скобках.

Comment: поясните про 
return "{$this->name['key']}";
[работает же](http://codepad.org/u6eiFmAX)

Comment: еще хороший пример когда надо

    return $this->surname."нетпробелапослепеременной"

пишется как 

    return "{$this->surname}нетпробелапослепеременной"

Comment: про ошибку - смотреть код выше)

Comment: Конкатенация? Ну шутите? Как ж я не догадался :)

Comment: ну вы особо то не прыгайте от радости) догадаться может и догадались - а написать ТС про это забыли...

Comment: Ещё раз, я всё верно написал. В данном примере они нафиг не нужны. Да и как по мне, они нигде особо не нужны, хотя тут уже дело чисто стиля, кому как удобнее всавлять переменные.

Answer (score 1):

ну вообще это для задания сложных выражений. [почитайте](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php)

> Сложный (фигурный) синтаксис
>
> Он называется сложным не потому, что
> труден в понимании, а потому что
> позволяет использовать сложные
> выражения.
>
> Любая скалярная переменная, элемент
> массива или свойство объекта,
> отображаемое в строку, может быть
> представлена в строке этим
> синтаксисом. Просто запишите выражение
> так же, как и вне строки, а затем
> заключите его в { и }. Поскольку { не
> может быть экранирован, этот синтаксис
> будет распознаваться только когда $
> следует непосредственно за {.
> Используйте {\$, чтобы напечатать {$.